# define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part

Tags: racket

I got an error. Can someone help me please?

define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part

```
(sqrt (+ (* (- x2 x1) (- x2 x1)) (* (- y2 y1) (- y2 y1))))
  (if( < circles-position abs(- r1 r2) "Interior" if(< (+ r1 r2) d) "External" "Intersect")))
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full code along with what you expect. Right now you have an extra paren, and all identifiers are unbound.

Answer (score 0):

The body of function must in the teaching languages be one expression only.
Above you have two expressions.

It's easier to read your code, if you indent `if` on three lines:

```
(sqrt (+ (* (- x2 x1) (- x2 x1))
         (* (- y2 y1) (- y2 y1))))

(if (< circles-position (abs (- r1 r2)))
    "Interior"
    (if (< (+ r1 r2) d)
        "External"
        "Intersect")))
```

Comment: No. There is still two expressions. The error says you can have only one expression in a body.